# how to get class attribute from xmlhttprequest using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I m trying to write a code that extract "codes" in the response obtained from an xmlhttprequest. I have come this far.

[image]

I m new to javascript and jquery , is my approach of extracting the codes like "ADDIDIONAL25" as show in the snap right ? Is there a better way of doing it ? I plan on extracting the "codes" from the array obtained as show in snap.

Comment: Looks fine to me. But SO is not the right place for such questions. If you have a concrete problem, we are happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var codes = $('.coupon_code_text', req.responseText).map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('code')
}).get();
console.log(codes)//it is an array containing all the code values
```